# Connection refused to injected S3Client devservice within @QuarkusIntegrationTest annotated test

Tags: java, quarkus

When trying to connect to my S3Client which is launched by the `quarkus.s3.devservices.enabled=true` property, I run into a ConnectionRefused exception during my containerized QuarkusIntegrationTests. I have a `Recordings` class which injects the S3 client like so

```java
@Path("")
public class Recordings {
    @Inject S3Client storage;
```

and onStart, attempts to check if a bucket exists, and if not creates it:

```java
@ConfigProperty(name = "storage.buckets.archives.name") String archiveBucket;

    void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent evt) {
        boolean exists = false;
        try {
            exists =
                    HttpStatusCodeIdentifier.isSuccessCode(
                            storage.headBucket(
                                            HeadBucketRequest.builder()
                                                    .bucket(archiveBucket)
                                                    .build())
                                    .sdkHttpResponse()
                                    .statusCode());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info(e);
        }
        if (!exists) {
            try {
                storage.createBucket(CreateBucketRequest.builder().bucket(archiveBucket).build());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem, is that these requests cannot go through during a `@QuarkusIntegrationTest` annotated test whenever I use the `Recordings` class. The connections are fine with `@QuarkusTest` annotated tests.

Is there a solution/workaround to this, or something fundamental that I am missing? Some configuration I am missing perhaps? Thanks!

**Connection Exception**

```java
2023-06-27 20:37:50,623 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.rea.com.cor.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext] (executor-thread-1) Restarting handler chain for exception exception: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection refused
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:111)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException.create(SdkClientException.java:47)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.utils.RetryableStageHelper.setLastException(RetryableStageHelper.java:223)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:83)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:56)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:48)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:31)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:193)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:103)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.doExecute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:171)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:82)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:179)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:76)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:45)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:56)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.listObjectsV2(DefaultS3Client.java:6538)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3ClientProducer_ProducerMethod_client_c3e44358d8bba829ee2f6ae63d6f9ef0b4609f3a_ClientProxy.listObjectsV2(Unknown Source)
```

**Relevant application.properties**

```
storage.buckets.archives.name=archivedrecordings
quarkus.s3.devservices.enabled=true
quarkus.s3.devservices.buckets=archivedrecordings

quarkus.aws.devservices.localstack.image-name=localstack/localstack:2.1.0
quarkus.aws.devservices.localstack.container-properties.START_WEB=0
quarkus.aws.devservices.localstack.container-properties.SERVICES=s3
quarkus.aws.devservices.localstack.container-properties.EAGER_SERVICE_LOADING=1
quarkus.aws.devservices.localstack.container-properties.SKIP_SSL_CERT_DOWNLOAD=1
quarkus.aws.devservices.localstack.container-properties.SKIP_INFRA_DOWNLOADS=1
quarkus.aws.devservices.localstack.container-properties.DISABLE_EVENTS=1
```

I run with with podman instead of docker.

I haven't tried to manually setup my own S3 instance as a TestContainer but I imagine it would work. The problem that I am confused about is that according to https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#launching-containers, DevServices containers should "just work" because of Quarkus magic, but I am sure I am missing something...